# Adding predefined elements to view through code

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible to add predefined elements, such as a linearlayout with text and buttons in it, to a scroll view through code

[(Code and Design)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7YVP.png), everytime the button_add is clicked it should add a duplicate of the linear layout above to the scroll view

Comment: I mean you could define that as a layout, and inflate it into a set of Views, and add that to your container layout inside the ScrollView. But at that point you're just reinventing a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`, so you may as well just use those and save yourself the hassle (or Compose if you want to learn that)